# pandas remove period after json normalize

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to build a tensorflow application in python, but after importing my data in I needed to normalize it. No problem there, except all my columns are now titled palm.velocity.x for example. I found a way to rename all of these columns as there are 230 of them in total so the old df.rename and similar methods aren't much help, unless they can be used like df.apply but from what I've looked at there doesn't seem to be a way.

Comment: Please post sample data, attempted code, and desired result (i.e., [mcve]).

Comment: @Parfait I put the code below as an answer in case anyone has the same problem I had

Answer (score 0):

```
def FixColumnHeading(column):
    columns = re.split(r'\.', column)
    name = []
    for word in range(len(columns)):
        if(word > 0):
            columns[word] = columns[word].capitalize()
        name.append(columns[word])
    
    newColumn = ''
    for part in name:
        newColumn += part
    return newColumn

normalisedData.columns = normalisedData.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: FixColumnHeading(x))
```

If anyone can think of a way to improve, please put what you would change below :)

Comment: `.lambda`, `.to_series`, and `.apply` is not necessary. Consider simply: `map(FixColumnHeading, normalisedData.columns)`